# How to find out if a Javascript variable has certain characters in it

Tags: javascript, if-statement

We have a quick order form which take in the product code (sku) and returns the product and enters a quantity of 1.

What we want to happen is any SKU that starts with EN9 we want the Quantity to be set to 0.

I have tried to work this out for myself but seem to be going no where as i have very minimum javascript experience.

This is the code which set everything

```
   var _parent = $j(this).parent().parent().parent();
    var _productid = $j(this).find('.prodid').val();
    var _sku = $j(this).find('.sku').html();
    var _name = $j(this).find('.name').html();
    var _price = $j(this).find('.pprice').val();
    var _temp_name = _name;

    _temp_name = _temp_name.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

    _parent.find('.txt-sku').html(_sku);
    _parent.find('.txt-pcode').val(_temp_name);
    _parent.find('.txt-qty').val(1);
    _parent.find('.pname').html(_name);
    _parent.find('.pqty').html(_price);
    _parent.find('.btn-addcart').attr('alt', _productid);
    $j('#allid').val($j('#allid').val()+','+_productid);
    $j(this).parent().hide();
    _key = '';
```

I can see  `_parent.find('.txt-qty').val(1);` sets the qty to 1 so i assumed i would have to wrap an IF statement around this.

I tried

```
    if ( _sku == ('EN9)){
        _parent.find('.txt-qty').val(1);}
else{
    _parent.find('.txt-qty').val(0);
}
```

But with no luck. SO i change -sku to .sku but still no luck.  If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Something like

```
if ( _sku.indexOf('EN9') > -1) {
        _parent.find('.txt-qty').val(0);}
else{
    _parent.find('.txt-qty').val(1);
}
```

This would set your quantity to 0 if EN9 is anywhere in the SKU.

If you need it at the start, specifically, check for the return of indexOf being 0 (I think should work).

```
if ( _sku.indexOf('EN9') == 0) {
        _parent.find('.txt-qty').val(0);}
else{
    _parent.find('.txt-qty').val(1);
}
```

Comment: Just a quick comment: according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), ES6 will have the `String.prototype.startsWith` method.

Comment: I had to change this a little bit to if ( _sku.indexOf('EN9') < 1) {} But it works perfect :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf` to check if a strings starts with another string, and then set the value accordingly

```
var qty = _sku.indexOf('EN9') === 0 ? '0' : '1';

_parent.find('.txt-qty').val(qty);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   if ( _sku == ('EN9)){
```

This is a messed up statement, as evidenced by the lack of sensible coloring here. :)

You want to check if `_sku` starts with `EN9`. You can do that by checking if the first 3 characters are equal to that:

```
if (_sku.slice(0,3) == 'EN9') {}
```